# How can I get PCAN dongles to work with macOS?

Tags: macos, network, hardware

I have a Perl program that's running a couple of CAN-servers to interact with a HIL setup. And with the connected Linux machines it's just the case of:

```
ifconfig -a | grep can
ip link set can0 type can bitrate 250000
ip link set up can0
```

And then I can reference these CAN-interfaces to my perl program via .ini files:

```
Port 9921
socketCAN:can0:250
```

But on the OSX system, the CAN-dongles doesn't even show up with `ifconfig -a`. I thought I just had to install the drivers from Mac-CAN for it to work. I get the dongles listed as available with the `can_moni` command tool.

If it simply isn't possible to achieve this on OSX, are there any alternative ways of doing it? I saw someone mention it being easier to just do this with a ubuntu container on the Mac system. But I have no experience with docker/containers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! When you say OS X are you meaning software released in 2012? If you could edit a specific build / version number in the post we might be able to offer more specific advice and not some general guesses. Depending on your hardware architecture - we can point out `system_profiler` or older commands to see what's connected and offer driver advice I hope. Also - if you link to specific CAN devices or a spec or specific hardware - answerers may guess less or find this post via search easier.

Comment: Also - interesting that the SO community sent you here - we will have some scripting and hardware knowledge but since there's thousands of posts there already on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can-bus  (where you may have asked the first question here about it) it seems well on scope there if you can show some code or details with an edit on your post over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CAN interfaces are handled differently on macOS than on Linux. In fact, they are handled mostly like they were on Linux before CAN on Linux was standardised on the SocketCAN interface.

The [PCAN dongles](https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-USB.199.0.html?&L=1) actually work well under macOS and you can definitely get your system working. I have used them with without any problems for years. However, you will need to code it slightly differently than you're used to on Linux.

On Linux, the SocketCAN interface means that CAN interfaces are listed as ordinary network interfaces that you can interact with using common commands such as the "ip" commands that you also use for setting up for example Ethernet network interfaces. That is not the case on macOS - and this is whhy you cannot see the CAN interface with `ifconfig -a`. It's not supposed to show up there.

Instead on macOS, similar to the situation on Windows, each vendor provides their own interface. Usually this is in the form of a shared library (think DLL) that you link together with your own program to access the CAN interface. Usually they also provide various utilities for setting up bitrates, timing, error handling and for doing packets dumps, monitoring bus load and other things.

For the PCAN dongles you can download that vendor specific interface here:

https://www.mac-can.com

On that page is also a monitor program that you can use to quickly view what is being transferred on the bus.

In order to use this interface with your Perl program, you will have to create Perl-bindings for the PCBUSB library. I'm not aware of any freely available implementation of that at the moment - you will have to roll your own. Fortunately the interface is really not that complicated.

Note that a project named [CANAPI](https://uv-software.github.io/CANAPI-Docs/#/) is underway to create a common interface for CAN interfaces across macOS, Windows and Linux. However, its use is not that widespread (yet).

A different way of going about it is to use Linux on Mac. You use a virtualisation system (such as VMware Fusion, Parallels Desktop, or one of the many free and open source systems) to run Linux. You then direct the CAN dongle, which is basically a USB device, into the virtual machine - and it is picked up by Linux just as on a normal Linux PC.

From there, you can set it up like any other CAN interface on Linux  using the ìp` command. And then you can run your Perl program unmodified. There is an overhead to virtualisation, so depending on your performance and latency requirements, it might not be a perfect solution.

Comment: Superb resources and advice here. Bookmarked and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the vendor has provided driver support to Apple, drivers may need to be supplied for the vendor on macOS. Your thought to run Linux as a virtual machine is going to be a well documented and supported path if you only have Windows or Linux drivers ( which you either have or are supplied in the distribution)

I would start with a free trial of VMWare or Parallels and configure your VM to have USB pass through to validate everything works with your chosen hardware on the Mac / cable / dongle end before you need to pay for a license.

I've not used the other virtualization engines but have heard very good things about Virtual Buddy (and other lightweight implementations) on Apple Silicon hardware:

- [VirtualBuddy](https://github.com/insidegui/VirtualBuddy)
- [Lightweight virtualisation in Ventura](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/11/17/lightweight-virtualisation-in-ventura/)

Comment: The interface you recommend here is not going to work as it is not a CAN interface. It is for LIN-bus, which is something completely different.

Comment: My intention was to show a sample driver that only mentions windows and Linux drivers - is that not an appropriate link for that context @jksoegaard ? If you could edit it to be correct, I would appreciate the assist

Comment: No, I don't think it makes sense at all. The question is about a specific product, for which the vendor provides Mac drivers. Then you give an example of a product for which the vendor does not provide Mac drivers and say that you need "serial drivers". Serial drivers are not involved at all (and yes, I know that LIN is a serial bus - but that is not the same as "serial drivers" in this context).

Comment: Thanks. I’ll excise both parts

Comment: LIN bus is quite different from CAN. It is like providing an answer about Firewire when the question is about USB.

Comment: Great, good to see an edit!